# Finding duplicates with two similar columns and one distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, duplicates, distinct

I am in a situation where I need to select rows that have the same content in two specific columns, AND distinct content in a third one. So far I got this for the two similar columns:

```
SELECT id, Title,
COUNT(*) AS NumOccurrences
FROM Table
GROUP BY id, Title
HAVING ( COUNT(*) > 1 )
```

I now need to specify a third distinct column in this query. Let's call it Ralph. This obviously does not work:

```
SELECT id, Title, DISTINCT Ralph,
COUNT(*) AS NumOccurrences
FROM Table
GROUP BY id, Title
HAVING ( COUNT(*) > 1 )
```

So what will?

Comment: What sql sever version are you using?

Comment: Sorry, SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from (
    SELECT id, Title, COUNT(*) AS NumOccurrences
    FROM Table t
    GROUP BY id, Title
    HAVING ( COUNT(*) > 1 )
) t
cross apply (
    select distinct Ralph
    from Table
    where id = t.id and Title = t.Title
) t2
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! But sadly:

"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

Comment: Maybe I should specify that it's not a unique id, it's a foreign id

Answer (score 0):

You can use COUNT(*) with OVER() clause

```
 ;WITH cte AS
 (       
  SELECT id, Title, Ralph, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id, Title) AS cnt
  FROM dbo.test11
  GROUP BY id, Title, Ralph
  ) 
  SELECT *
  FROM cte
  WHERE cnt > 1
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/89227/1)